# How to use Inheritant Class to pass parameters to base class?

Tags: c++

When I compile my code it returns 0 as result.

I suspect that my class declaration is not passing to base class the parameters, however I dont understand the reason for that not happening.

I am struggling on how to define base class and inherant class and connect them with passing values between them.

The problem I am trying to solve is:

On their expiration day the holder throws n-times a regular dice. The outcome is dened by: max[(S - X); 0] for DiveDerivativeCall and max[(X - S); 0] for DiveDerivativePut, where X is the strike price and S is sum of n results rounded down to the nearest even number. Both of these two classes inherit after the base class DiceDerivative. An example of
implementation of these classes in the main() function is provided below.

```
class DiceDerivative{
    double expiry;
    double nThrow;
    int k;
    double rf;
    string type;
    int nSim;

public:

    double rollDie(int turns){

        int roll;
        int i;
        int min = 1; // the min number a die can roll is 1
        int max = 6;// this->dieSize; // the max value is the die size
        int sum = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < turns; i++){

            roll = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;

            sum+= roll;

        }
        return  (sum % 2 == 0) ? sum: (sum -1);
    };   // Attribute (int variable)

    double price(int nSim) {

        int payoff = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        int i;

        for (i=0; i<nSim; i++) {

        if (type == "Call") {

            //specify the calculation for Call price
            int a = rollDie(nThrow);


            payoff = max(a - k,0);
            sum += payoff;

            cout << sum << type << " ";
        }
        else {

            //specify the calculation Put price
            int a = rollDie(nThrow);

            payoff = max(k- a,0);
            sum += payoff;

            cout << a << sum << type << " ";


        }

        };
         return (sum/nSim)*exp(-rf*expiry);

    }

};

class DiceDerivativeCall : public DiceDerivative{

public:

    double expiry;
    double nThrow;
    double k;
    double rf;


    DiceDerivativeCall(double expiry_, double nThrow_, double k_, double rf_)
    {
        string type = "Call";
        expiry_ = expiry;
        nThrow_ = nThrow;
        k_ = k;
        rf_ = rf;


    };



};

class DiceDerivativePut : public DiceDerivative{

public:

    double expiry;
    double nThrow;
    double k;
    double rf;


    DiceDerivativePut(double expiry_, double nThrow_, double k_, double rf_){
        string type = "Put";
        expiry_ = expiry;
        nThrow_ = nThrow;
        k_ = k;
        rf_ = rf;


    };



};



#endif /* DiceDerivative_hpp */


int main()

{



    srand ( time ( NULL ) ) ;

    DiceDerivativeCall myDDCall ( 1 , 5 , 12 , 0.05 ) ;

    cout << "Price of myDDCall is: " << myDDCall .price(10) <<"\n" ;


}

// returns: Price of myDDCall is: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Results should be the price calculation based on the Price functions that I defined in base class.

Comment: You should read introductory texts about inheritance. What stands out is that you define the members `double expiry;
    double nThrow;
    double k;
    double rf;` again in the derived class. But since it inherits from the base class, *these members are already members* of the derived class as welll.

Comment: Also, things like `expiry_ = expiry` should be `expiry = expiry_`, otherwise you are replacing a function's paramater with the value of a member, but you want the opposite, right?

Comment: @Ripi2 you are totally right! this fixed the issue of passing the elements! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just override price() function in DiceDerivativeCall class.
And also see about virtual table concept in CPP, that will give a clear concept of inheritance. 
[virtual Table:](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/125-the-virtual-table/)